# How to get the file path in html <input type="file"> in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, filepath

Can somebody pls tell me how to get the filepath using html `<input type="file">` in PHP?

Here are my codes:

**`index.php`**

```
<form action="csv_to_database.php" method="get" >
 <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
 <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and in **`csv_to_database.php`**

```
<?php

 if (isset($_GET['csv_file'])) {

 $row = 1;

  if (($handle = fopen($_GET['csv_file'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
   }
   fclose($handle);
  }

 } 
?>
```

My problem is, it only works when the csv data is in the same directory as my php files. I think I need to get the file path but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't just use the `$_GET` you've got now. Your file is based in `$_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"]`.

Best you review [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp), that basically says you need to do something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["csv_file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["csv_file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

And you can go from there. Use `move_uploaded_file` if you want to move the file from the temp location, also explained in the tutorial :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you would gain a lot from taking a look at the following link: [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

First of all, you should change your form method to `post`, and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Then you can get the temporary file path from `$_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']`.

Answer (score -1):

In your call to fopen, use `$_GET['csv_file']['tmp_name']` - this points to the file on the server immediately after upload.