# Get the path to the selected file

Tags: php, html

Is there a way that the following script show the full path to the file and not just the file name?

```
 $DataSaveDirectory= $_POST['datasavedir'];

 Data Save Directory: <input name="datasavedir" type="file" VALUE="<?PHP print $DataSaveDirectory ; ?>">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814155/how-to-get-the-file-path-in-html-input-type-file-in-php and also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: this will fail `$_POST['datasavedir']` because we're dealing with files.

Comment: @Fred So what is the alternative ?

Comment: `$_FILES['datasavedir']` and using a valid enctype as well as a POST method. However, your question is unclear. Can you elaborate on what it is exactly that you wish to achieve? Do you want to show the full path of the uploaded image? or from a fetched file already on your server?

Comment: I want to choose a file from my computer and save some data and I want to see the full path on my webpage when I choose the file. For example: Desktop/test/test.txt. I only see test.txt now.