# How to get upload file local path

Tags: html, file-type

Usual file upload code:

```
<input type="file">
```

this type show, upload file only. but want to get where file placed in client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get full path where file is stored on device, this is not possible, as far as I know.

You should get temporary path, which should be used to do something with the file, for example copy to the server.

More about:

[How to get the file path in html <input type="file"> in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814155/how-to-get-the-file-path-in-html-input-type-file-in-php)